# Rails 3, rake db:test:prepare doesn't work when using a postgres Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake

I have a Rails 3.2.1 project that I'm trying to run my specs on.

When I run:
rake

> rake aborted! PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter
>   "search_path": "example" DETAIL:  schema "example" does not exist :
>   SET search_path TO example

From what I can work out, rake db:test:prepare drops the test database and then attempts to recreate it from the schema.rb. The thing is, database.yml has the line

> schema_search_path: example

so when it tries to reconnect, it fails with the above error.

I think my question is, how can I get rake db:test:prepare to setup the schema_path too?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a bit of code to the db:create task that creates the schema. Put this in a rake task, for exmaple 'APP_ROOT/lib/tasks/db_create_schema.rake'

```
namespace :db do
  task :create do
    config = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env].merge!({'schema_search_path' => 'public'})
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE SCHEMA schema_name")
  end
end
```

https://gist.github.com/4280172

Answer (score -1):

You should set the `schema_search_path` in your config/database.yml

e.g.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: password
  #host: localhost
  #port: 5432
  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  schema_search_path: example
```

Comment: care to explain why down voting my answer?